# DocumentDb Client receiving invalid api version documentdb ensure a valid x-ms-version header value is passed

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm doing some local DocumentDb development through emulator.  My DocumentDb Emulator is a month or two old now.  When I download latest Nuget components for DocumentDb Client I can't connect to it and I get the error: invalid api version documentdb ensure a valid x-ms-version header value is passed

So... I know what I need to do (I think).  Its adjust the x-ms-version header so it matches my older DocumentDb Emulator install.  The question is, how do I change the version number on the request, AND what should I change the version number to?

I don't think its an acceptable solution to constantly be upgrading my DocumentDb local emulator.  Especially when there is no backup/restore of my data etc.

What's the best approach here to work with this?

Thanks!

James

Comment: One thing I noticed I can do is just update to an older DocumentDb Client package, but this seems a little backwards.  Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 4):

As this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/querying-documentdb-resources-using-the-rest-api) mentioned about **x-ms-version** of DocumentDB REST API:

> The version of DocumentDB REST service. The latest version is used when the header is not provided.

And for the supported REST API versions by the Azure DocumentDB service, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/index).

I have tested and found that when using `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core 1.1.0`, the `x-ms-version` would be configured as `2017-01-19`, While for `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core 1.0.0` the `x-ms-version` would be `2016-07-11`.

Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core 1.1.0 is released at February 16, 2017. You could download the latest [DocumentDB Emulator version 1.11.136.2](https://aka.ms/documentdb-emulator).

> The question is, how do I change the version number on the request, AND what should I change the version number to?

DocumentDb client library provides you with a simple way to access your documentdb, as I known, the library does not provide you with a method to configure `x-ms-version`.

> I don't think its an acceptable solution to constantly be upgrading my DocumentDb local emulator. Especially when there is no backup/restore of my data etc.

The Azure DocumentDB Emulator just provides a local environment that emulates the Azure DocumentDB service for development purposes.

> **Data created in one version of the DocumentDB Emulator is not guaranteed to be accessible when using a different version**. If you need to **persist your data for the long term, it is recommended that you store that data in an Azure DocumentDB account**, rather than in the DocumentDB Emulator.

If you do not want to constantly upgrade your DocumentDb emulator to persist your data, you need to leverage specified version of DocumentDB client library to access your DocumentDb emulator.

Comment: I have just encountered this version error, using the DocumentDB.Core library version 1.3.0, and can confirm this was resolved by upgrading to the latest emulator (at time of writing, this is 1.13.58.2). In my case, data was retained. I did not uninstall the previous version - the installer for the new version appears to detect and uninstall existing installations automatically. Perhaps that helps someone... I am also concerned that we would face this issue if attempting to use the emulator with an older version of the client? Say for debugging an existing Production app?